# copy data of a project(from a project table) from one database to other in Oracle

Tags: oracle, copy, backup

Could somebody tell me how to do this in Oracle:

I have a table named project in which there a multiple projects. I want to copy the data of a particular project from the source database to another database. The project doesn't exist(in the project table) in the destination database.

I want something like: 
copy from sourceDatabase to destinationDatabase
           create new_table using select * from project where name='Name of the project to be copied'

Answer (score 2):

If you can and are allowed to create `` `database links ``, create one and then copy the data over the database link.
That would be: on the destination db:

```
create database link db_link
connect to <username> 
identified by <password>
using '<connection_string>";
```

then

```
insert into projects 
select * from projects@db_link
where ....
```

Or,alternatively, try the `copy` command of SQL*Plus.

```
SQL> copy from <db_src> to <db_dest> append projects using select * from projects where ....
```

Comment: Thanks Rene. Will this copy all the data/dependencies of the project at the source database to the destination database?

Comment: To clarify my question, there are other tables in the source which contain data that is related to the project that I am copying. Should I just copy each of those tables separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the expdp and impdp command to extract tables and import it anywhere you want.